# Libre Office won't Print checkbox forms correctly

Tags: lubuntu, printing, libreoffice, hplip

I converted a $150 chromebook to Lubuntu 13.10 as a gift to my mom, but she has to print these work forms all the time that have checkboxes in Libre Office. However, we have now tried three seperate wireless printers, two of them supported through HPLIP, and all of them working with other kinds of documents. It prints checkboxes and then the word "checkbox 2" in bold immediately following the checkbox, so that all of the words are covered up by the bold lettering. Needless to say, this probably won't be working. Her forms aren't editable either, so we can't just put some whitespace between them. I was wondering what the problem might be, because it does work on a windows 7 starter machine.

Comment: I would say that is either a bug in Libre Office or with your printer driver. What format are these forms?

Comment: @Mateo the forms are in the .ODT format. I am going to try using a virtual windows machine inside Lubuntu and see if my mom can understand how that works. Does that sound like it will work?

Comment: New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: I upgraded the kernel version so it really is almost the same as 14.04.

Comment: All the other updates are the important thing, this bug may even be fixed in newer versions of libreoffice...

Answer (score 1):

It seems they left the default names on each check box, instead of creating the fields properly. Instead of placing text next to the check box, the "Label field" should be used and the bounding box expanded to fit the text, or at least remove the text in the label field, instead they shrunk the bounding box to obscure the text.

[image]

Right click on each check box and go to → Control... → Label → and delete the contents of the boxes.

[image]

Also check and make sure these settings are set properly: [image]

If that doesn't work it most likely a problem with the printer driver.